# Error propagation on correlated Poisson samples

Tags: poisson-distribution, error, ratio

If I have a set of $n$ tuples ($b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,x,y,z$), where $b_1, b_2, b_3$ and $b_4$ are counters ruled by $P_1, P_2, P_3$ and $P_4$ Poisson distributions (error on the counters are $\sqrt{b_1}$, etc.) and $x, y$ and $z$ are ruled by real valued distributions.

From it I select a subset of tuples $m$ according to a condition on $x,y$ and $z$, e.g. $x > P_I$. That subset will have certain $b_1', b_2', b_3'$ and $b_4'$ values for the counters.

If e.g. I compute the $b_1'\div b_1$, what's the error on that ratio?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends upon what question you're trying to answer. For proportion estimation, we are rarely if ever interested in accounting for random variation in the denominator. That's because, under the independence assumption, we'd expect to obtain the same proportion regardless of how many individuals we sample. So we condition upon the denominator (pretend it's observed and nonrandom). The proportion estimation becomes as simple as basic statistics, and a confidence interval can be obtained using normal approximations to a proportion: $p = b_1'/b_1$, 95% CI ($p - 1.96 \sqrt{p(1-p)/b_1}, p + 1.96 \sqrt{p(1-p)/b_1})$. This, of course, has problems, but I figured your question dealt with the apparent randomness of $b_1$.